# Count how many columns of a numpy matrix contain all positive values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check how many columns of a numpy array/matrix have only positive values.

I took my matrix and printed `A>0` and got `True` and `False` and then I tried `any` and `all` functions but didn't succeed.

```
In [55]: a = np.array([[13, 21, 12],
                       [21, -1,  6],
                       [ 1, 10,  2],
                       [41,  1,  4]])
```

The output should be `2`.

I saved the matrix `A` in `B` and tried writing:

```
B.all(axis=1).any()>0
```

Comment: Why the output?

Comment: `(a > 0).all(0).sum()`--->`2`?

Answer (score 0):

This function counts the number of column whose elements are all greater than 0:

```
def count(mat):
    counter = 0
    tmp = mat > 0
    for col in tmp.T:
        if all(col):
             counter += 1
    return counter
```

How does this function work?

First it assigns to tmp a matrix of boolean values indicating if the corresponding value of the original matrix was greater than 0, then it iterates through the transpose of such matrix and checks if all the values are True, meaning they are all greater than 0.

The transpose contains the columns of the original matrix. Whey you create a numpy array you pass the rows to the function. By transposing, the array will contain the columns.